# Can we configure Maven to use different JDK versions for different modules?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I have a requirement where I need few modules to be built on JDK 1.6 and others on JDK 1.7. WHat I have done is using compiler plugin in specific module to provide the source and target version like below. But I am wondering if there is a better solution for this.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Do you need to build on JDK 1.7, 1.6 or do have class files only for JDK 7/6 ?

Comment: The classes are for jdk 6 & 7.

Comment: If you build with JDK 6 the files will run on JDK 7 ... what exactly is the need?

Comment: few modules need at least JDK 7 as it uses jars only compatible for JDK 7.

Comment: Ok for those they need JDK 7 you have to set source/target to 1.7 and for those you need to be compatible with JDK 7 compiling with JDK 7 is enough. The point is if you need really different JDK's (for example JDK6, JDK7, JDK8) you have to use maven-toolchains https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html It's important if you need to be sure for compiling with JDK 7 but be compatible with JDK 6 you have to check bootstrap classpath (best would be to use the appropriate JDK).

Comment: Furthermore I strongly recommend to upgrade your maven-compiler-plugin (The version 2.0.2 is 13 years+ old)..

Comment: Thanks to all for the suggestion! I was able to compile different module with different types of jdk version but some how I wasn't able to run the application successfully on jboss. I ended up using 2 poms in same branch and renamed one pom with a custom name and build both ears separately. This helped me reduce the complication as well.

Comment: If you need two poms? Does not make sense. If you deploy to jboss your compilation must be using the max Java version which is supported by JBoss.. that's it... Than you can't the JDK ...